# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при создании сервера, порт открывался?(C++)

Tags: c++

возник такой вопрос при создании сервера, можно ли, чтобы программа работала через выбранный порт, если он до этого был закрыт, при этом не напрягая пользователя? И на сколько это будет "законно"? Как я понимаю программа должна вносить разрешения в брандмауэр виндовс, но я точно не уверен. Буду признателен, если кто-то объяснит, а если и с кодом поможет, то будет еще круче :D

Answer (score 0):

Можно, если пользователь разрешит и запустит от имени администратора. Не забывайте про настройки Firewall'а и возможные другие проблемы. Лучше оставьте заморочки с открытием портов пользователю, так будет надёжнее.